# excel:separate rows to different sheets according to a column values

Tags: excel, vba

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|  a  |    b     |    c     |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 101 | 12:13:00 | employee |
| 102 | 12:15:00 | customer |
| 103 | 12:20:00 | employee |
| 102 | 12:16:00 | customer |
| 103 | 18:15:00 | employee |
| 101 | 18:18:00 | customer |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

how to separate rows to different sheets according to a column values automatically

finally get three sheets:

column a values 101

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|  a  |    b     |    c     |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 101 | 12:13:00 | employee |
| 101 | 18:18:00 | customer |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

column a values 102

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|  a  |    b     |    c     |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 102 | 12:15:00 | customer |
| 102 | 12:16:00 | customer |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

column a values 103

```
+-----+----------+----------+
|  a  |    b     |    c     |
+-----+----------+----------+
| 103 | 12:20:00 | employee |
| 103 | 18:15:00 | employee |
+-----+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
Sub test()
Dim sht As Worksheet, r As Range

For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = Worksheets("_" & r.Value)
    If sht Is Nothing Then
        With Worksheets.Add
            .Name = "_" & r.Value
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .Value = r.Value
                .Offset(, 1).Value = r.Offset(, 1).Value
                .Offset(, 2).Value = r.Offset(, 2).Value
            End With
        End With
    Else
        With sht.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Value = r.Value
            .Offset(, 1).Value = r.Offset(, 1).Value
            .Offset(, 2).Value = r.Offset(, 2).Value
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a loop from the last row up, moving every row with a matching value; but that could require running through the table several times if not sorted.

You could do it in one loop by filtering a value and transferring all visible cells until none remain.

I would either use the filter method or create an array of unique values and loop through the array without the overhead that comes with filtering.... but it would depend on the table size and context of the application, like if i wanted to keep a filtered table on a 4th sheet.

Comment: could you please offer a concrete way and use the data to verify it?and the acceptance will be yours..thanks !